# pyHook ошибка с кириллицей

Tags: python, python-3.x, hook

Написал что-то на подобие простого кейлоггера, но столкнулся с проблемой: Программа вылетает как только перехожу в другое окно, в названии или пути которого есть кириллица

С ошибкой

> F:\Programs\Python36\python.exe F:/Files/MyProjects/KLPy/main.py
>
> TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments:
> 'msg', 'vk_code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and
> 'win_name'
>
> Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Код программы

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    data = str(event.Key)
    f = open('Logfile.txt', 'a')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()

hook = pyHook.HookManager()
hook.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hook.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Как это пофиксить?

Comment: приведите полный traceback

Comment: @jfs полный лог ошибки?

Comment: если со словом traceback не встречались, попробуйте 1/0 в Питон консоль ввести.

Comment: @jfs Изменил в вопросе, это все что там выведено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В pyHook не используется Unicode. В его форке **pyhook_py3k** добавлена поддержка Unicode. 
Поддержка Unicode выполнена в файле **cpyHook.i**, который в бинарной сборке скомпилирован в **_cpyHook.xxx.pyd**, поэтому так просто его не изменить.

Варианты решения проблемы:

- скомпилировать pyhook_py3k под Ваши нужды;
- использовать Pywinauto ([пример установки хуков на клавиатуру](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/hook_and_listen.py))